# Zyxel router keeps restarting when wireless is switched on

Tags: wireless-router

I have a client with a Zyxel router. We just can't figure this out but it seems that there is something wireless on or off the network that is causing the router to reboot. When the wireless is switched off the up time just keeps rising, as soon as the wireless is switched on the router might stay on for 20 minutes then reboots.

Most of the devices on the network are Macs.

Does anyone have a similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need to replace the power adapter. Contact our free US-based Tech Support. http://us.zyxel.com/Support/Contact-us.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply but It's happening to more than one router though :S

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. I believe the modem has some trouble when there is file sharing stuff.

When you switch on the wireless, other devices try to access the file sharing and that will cause the modem to reboot. If you are using windows 7, try to open `My computer`. On the left side there is a tree called `Network`. If you click on it, it will make your modem reboot.

I have disabled my network discovery (if you can do this on all your devices, it would lessen the risk of getting rebooted). You can find it in `Network and sharing center`, click on change advanced sharing and turn off the network discovery for Home and Public profile. This is all I notice about. I bought the modem from TM (Telekom Malaysia).

My modem model is `TM6841G`

Comment: Avoid using textspeak in your posts, it looks horrible and makes it hard to understand.